# Filtering doesn`t work on three level dimension

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap-cube, slicers

can someone help me out maybe?

I have the following mdx:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

and the following structure of the Relationship dimension:

[image]

And when in excel I try to filter on the attribute hierarchy: User Story Team, it only works for the two level user hierarchy named: Feature-User Story Hierarchy, but for some reason for the three level hierarchy named: Relationship it doesn`t work

Can someone please help me understand how to fix it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution

When I used the Attribute User Story Team from the the separate Dimension for the User Story, it didn`t filter for the three level hierarchy

However, when I use the attribute hierarchy: User Story Team from the DWH Dim Relationships dimension instead, it works as needed